# Fatal error when using a prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

This is the situation. I created 3 PHP files, all in the same project folder:

1. constants.php
2. Mysql.php (class)
3. index.php

When I run index.php, I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\MyBlog\MyClass\MySql.php on line #

constants.php:

```
<?php
//Define constent her
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'myblog');
```

Mysql.php:

```
<?php 

require_once 'constants.php';

class MySql{
        private $conn;
        protected $_query;

    function __constructert() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or
        die("There was a probelm connecting the database");
        return $this->conn;
    }
    protected function _prepareQuery() 
   {
//her the line that problem come from beetwen the () of if : 
      if (!$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($this->_query)) {
         trigger_error("Problem preparing query", E_USER_ERROR);
      }
      return $stmt;
   }

    protected function _dynamicBindResults($stmt){
        $meta=$stmt->result_metadata();
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
            print_r($field);
        }
    }

    function query($query){
        $this->_query = filter_var($query,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $stmt = $this->_preparequery();
        $stmt->execute();
        $results=$this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);
    }
```

index.php:

```
<? PHP
        include 'MySql.php';
        $Db= new MySql();
        $Db->query("select * from status");
```

As I said, when I run index.php, I get this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\MyBlog\MyClass\MySql.php on line

That line is:

```
if (!$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($this->_query)) {
```

For more info, I tested the connection to the database, and it's okay. I tested if the `_query` property takes the SQL statement, and it does.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for your class `MySQL` is named `__constructert()`; The correct constructor name is [`__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

With the invalid name, the line `$Db = new MySQL();` creates the object but the constructor is never called - thereby never creating the MySQL connection / `$conn` object.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here `->_preparequery();`

Change it to the following :

```
function query($query){         
  $this->_query = filter_var($query,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);         
  $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();         
  $stmt->execute();         
  $results=$this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);     
}
```